# Convert android json parsing in c#

Tags: c#, android, json, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to port one android app into windows phone app, and in that I stuck at json parsing task. Can anyone please guide me how I will achieve in c#.

JSON

```
{
  "chapter1": {
    "name": "Successful Sales",
    "page1": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-1.html"
    },
    "page2": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-2.html"
    },
    "page3": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-3.html"
    },
    "page4": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-4.html"
    },
    "page5": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-5.html"
    },
    "page6": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-6.html"
    },
    "page7": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-7.html"
    },
    "page8": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-8.html"
    },
    "page9": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-9.html"
    },
    "page10": {
      "url": "Chapter-304/Page-10.html"
    }
  }
}
```

android code

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(courselist).nextValue();  
    /*courselist - nothing but json string*/
    int jsonLength = jsonObject.length();
    JSONObject[] subJson = new JSONObject[jsonLength];
    String[] courseString = new String[jsonLength];
    Vector<Object> mVectorElements = new Vector<Object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
        try {
            subJson[i] = jsonObject.getJSONObject(jsonObject.names()
                    .getString(i));
            courseString[i] = jsonObject.names().getString(i) + "@@@@"
                    + subJson[i].getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(courseString);

    for (int j = 0; j < courseString.length; j++) {
        mVectorElements.add(courseString[j].split("@@@@")[1]);
    }
```

I am trying this using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken parse but after parsing how I will get each and every single element. Please correct me if I am using wrong way.

Update:
Below is what I am trying to do get the property name inside the JObject but loop is not working.

```
    jsonObject = (JObject) JToken.Parse(courselist);

    foreach (JObject content in jsonObject.Children<JObject>())
    {
        foreach (JProperty prop in content.Properties())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are showing us Android code but you are asking how to do it in C#. Please show BOTH the Android code AND the C# code so we can see where you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(courselist);

foreach (JProperty prop in jsonObject.Properties())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(prop.Name);  // chapter1
    Debug.WriteLine(prop.Value["name"].ToString());  // Successful Sales

    // Get page numbers and URLs
    int count = 0;
    foreach (JProperty pageProp in ((JObject)prop.Value).Properties())
    {
        if (pageProp.Name != "name")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(pageProp.Name + ": " + 
                            pageProp.Value["url"].ToString());
            count++;
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine(count + " total pages.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working as expected. But If I use JToken to parse then property is null, why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Which property is null?

Comment: One more help can you please suggest how I will get total page and its Urls. thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Json2Csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) site and paste either your entire JSON string or URL to the JSON and click on Generate button. This creates all the required classes for your JSON response.

For the Json deserialization :

```
Rootobject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(courselist);
```

Take a look at this tutorial : [Parsing JSON in Windows Phone Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/02/25/parsing-json-in-windows-phone-apps.aspx)

P.S : It uses an other deserialization  method.